# How to display changes in web browser when Building a RESTful Web Service using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-mvc

I am following this tutorial:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

After completing the tutorial I run everything in my web browser on my local host and everything seems to work.However when I make changes in the java code (I made errors on purpose) I can still run everything in the web browser. What do I need to do in order for it to change due to my code changes? I guess I should mention that I am using eclipse and have installed maven as a plugin.

Comment: Just running a java application regularly will not provide you with hot-deploy features. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-hotswapping since you are using Spring Boot

Comment: Which part do you mean that I should look at? There is a lot of things to read and I don't know what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the source code, but not the compiled files. Your service is using the created "gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar" file. This is not affected by your code changes.

Jump into the tutorial again where it says: 
"Build an executable JAR"
This will rebuild your jar file. Afterwards you will have to restart your service like you did in the chapter "Run the service".

Comment: I have only installed maven as a plugin in eclipse and I don't have Gradle. Is there anyway to do this directly in eclipse and not by using the command prompt? (When I write commands including maven int the command prompt it doesn't work)

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with eclipse. But you could try to clean your cleanup(delete) your "gs-rest-service-0.1.0.jar" file and your build directory. Rebuilding the project may recreate this jar file.

Comment: Which maven plugin are you using in Eclipse? If you right click on the pom.xml, you should see the option in the menu "Run as" and select "maven install". It's a good idea if you look into the environment path's you have set in your command line, it's easier to run certain maven commands from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using maven as a plugin a choose to install it in order to use the command prompt.